# How to deepcopy `char *` to std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, std

Having `char *` and its `int length` how to deep copy it into `stringstream`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::stringstream::write(s, length);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).

Note if the `char*` is null terminated `operator<<()` can be used instead and the `length` does not need to be supplied:

```
std::stringstream s;
const char* buf = "hello";
s << buf;
```

Comment: and what if I get void * and its length? and wannt to get it as `char*`?

Comment: and char * is not a C string but array

Comment: @myWallJSON: If you have `void * p`, then you'll need to convert it (`static_cast<char const *>(p)`) before using `write`.

Comment: Shall I make any changes to size?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't write fullfil your requirements?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) and this [one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/)